# Why is changing this text breaking my Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some javascript that changes the text inside of a button, shown here:

```js
$('#studentDocument_File_EditShow').click(function() {
  if ($(this).html().indexOf('Cancel') > 0) {
    $(this).html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> Edit');
  } else {
    $(this).html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Cancel');
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="studentDocument_File_EditShow" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" 
    aria-hidden="true"></span> Cancel</button>
```

However, if I change the "cancel" text in line 5, my html does not revert.

How could I fix this so I can just have a glyphicon with no text attached to it?

Comment: Works fine in this page. Are you changing other html that contains this button also?

Comment: what is exactly your problem

Comment: If you remove "Cancel" you break the condition in the `if` statement which needs this text as distinction between the two states.

Comment: To make it independent of the text value check classes instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the text in `indexOf('Cancel')`

See below.

```js
$('#studentDocument_File_EditShow').click(function() {
      if ($(this).html().indexOf('No longer edit') > 0) {
        $(this).html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> Edit');
      } else {
        $(this).html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> No longer edit');
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="studentDocument_File_EditShow" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" 
    aria-hidden="true"></span> Cancel</button>
```

Comment: duh. This worked, what a silly thing to overlook. Thanks!